# Can't find an element by class name in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I need to press the "Play" button

[image: HTML]

**My code:**
*cy.get('.button.button__slider-play.button__rounded-xl').should('be.visible').click();*

**But I have response :**
*Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: button.button.button__slider-play.button__rounded-xl, but never found it.*

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Add your html to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no iframe or shadow DOM, you can do like this:

```js
cy.get('button[class*="slider-play"]).should('be.visible').click();
```

In case, click doesn't work you can use `click({force: true})`

```js
cy.get('button[class*="slider-play"]).should('be.visible').click({force: true});
```